# Keep the space after completion for some characters in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, line-editor

Zsh has a bit of completion-related automation that's nice most of the time: after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, a space is inserted automatically (or some other appropriate character such as `,` inside braces).

I want to keep this feature except in one case: when I type `&` or `|` after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I don't want the space to be removed. I prefer the space to be removed on a `;`, and I definitely want to suppress the automatically-inserted comma when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> `}` in a brace enumeration.

This feature works by default both in the “old” (`compctl`) and the “new” (`compadd`) completion systems. I'm only interested in the new system.

How can I tune the automatic suppression of the automatic suffix inserted by completion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This feature can be tuned with [`ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-ZLE_005fREMOVE_005fSUFFIX_005fCHARS) and [`ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-ZLE_005fSPACE_005fSUFFIX_005fCHARS) shell parameters.

- If the `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS` variable is set, it should contain a set of characters that, when typed, will cause automatic suffixes from the completion to be removed. If `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS` is unset, the default behaviour equates to

  ```
  ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS=$' \t\n;&|'
  ```
- For characters set in `ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS` suffices are replaced with a space. It also takes precedence over `ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS`

---

So in order to get your desired behaviour, it should be sufficient to set

```
ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS=$'|&'
```

It seems that the automatically inserted `,` in brace enumerations is always removed when typing `}`.

Although `zshparam(1)` mentions that certain completion systems may override this behaviour it seems to work just fine with the "new" `compsys` (you called it `compadd`)